# Tortoise SVN merge of 2 repositories

Tags: svn

I have 2 repositories that I would like to merge. I would like to take the 1st repo [PRIMARY] and pull in all the content from the 2nd repo [SECONDARY]. They don't share content so I don't need merge different versions of the same file. I would like to retain file history of the elements in SECONDARY when they are pulled into PRIMARY.

How would I go about this using TortoiseSVN 1.5.2?

Answer (score 6):

In short: You can't (at least with Tortoise).

But the [Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#multi-merge) describes a way (Using svn dump and svn load).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that you can merge the histories (PRIMARY will have r123 and SECONDARY will have its own r123) but you could [setup](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) an [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s04.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's even possible to merge two repositories in this way.  Even if you could do it then you'd still have the problem that the old revision numbers are now meaningless.